# Auto installer click continue etc, while the process.waitforexit() is active

Tags: c#

I'm coding an auto-installer based on feature events, such as :

- Easy coded automatic installer, (but with great effort working on ALL programs).

now there's an problem i got stuck on, wich is how do I execute sendkeys etc while the program is in `process.waitforexit()`?

```
try
        {
            foreach (string checkedItem in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                if (checkedItem.Contains("."))
                {
                    string str = checkedItem;
                    if (str.Contains("."))
                    {
                        /* haal de rest achter de . eraf om een map ervan te maken. */
                        int index = str.IndexOf('.');
                        string folder = str.Substring(0, index);
                        string pad = Application.StartupPath;
                        try
                        {
                            /* Start de programma. */
                            bool started = false;
                            var process = new Process();
                            process.StartInfo.FileName = pad + "/data/" + folder + "/" + checkedItem;
                            started = process.Start();
                            /* Haal de informatie op van de programma's die opgestart worden. */
                            var processID = process.Id;
                            var processNAAM = process.ProcessName;
                            textBox1.Text += "Gevonden - ID: " + processID + "     NAAM: " + processNAAM + Environment.NewLine;
                            textBox1.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) + "  -  " + "Installatie Keuze wordt opgestart." + Environment.NewLine;
                            /* Wacht totdat het programma klaar is! */
                                process.WaitForExit();
                            textBox1.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) + "  -  " + "Installatie Geslaagd!" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                        }
```

If someone is able to help me out here, it'll be appreciated alot :D

Comment: Your (main-)thread is blocking when waiting for the process. Maybe you should create a background-thread which watches for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Process.WaitForInputIdle()` so you know the other process is ready for input, then use SendKeys as needed then maybe call `Process.WaitForExit()` if you really need to wait for it to exit.

**Edit**

Replace your line `process.WaitForExit();` with below and update with the keys you need %C probably

```
process.WaitForInputIdle();
SendKeys.SendWait("Your Key Strokes");
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: added an example of what I mean

Comment: is there a way to make it like while (process.waitforexit()){do something}else{break;}?

Comment: you can use process.HasExited to do that

Comment: if you really need to do somthing else do not call process.waitforexit